# Custom NuGet Feed Works for One Project, Crashes for Other

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

We recently setup a custom NuGet feed.  Two different developers use it for two different projects.  It works fine for each of them, on their respective computers with their respective projects.

Today one developer checked out the other developer's project.  When using the NuGet Package Manager at the solution level to try and update Nuget packages for the other project via the custom feed, the following error is displayed in the package manager where the list of packages would normally be shown:

> Error occured:\nThe context is already tracking a different entity with the same resource Uri.

Googling the error uncovered some instances of this error text unrelated to NuGet caused by the casing of the URL being other than expected.  However, we verified that the casing of the NuGet feed URL is all lower case for both solutions.

What could cause this issue, and how can we correct it?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, one of the projects in the solution was not updated to reference an external DLL via NuGet.  Instead, it was referencing the local file system.

Something about having MyDll.dll as both a NuGet reference and a file system reference caused this error.

Updating the project to also pull MyDll.dll from NuGet resolved the issue.